# geom_col displaying incorrect number of values

Tags: r

[image: this is what happens]I am trying to create a stacked plot from likert questions. There are 4 questions (each have the same amount of respondents, 204).

```
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x = value, y = question, fill = choices), position = "stack") +
  ggtitle("mask likert scale questions") +
  ylab("questions") +
  xlab("# of people") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

reproducible df

| question | value | choices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ques1 | 5 | strongly agree |
| ques1 | 5 | strongly agree |
| ques1 | 4 | agree |
| ques1 | 4 | agree |
| ques2 | 1 | strongly disagree |
| ques2 | 1 | strongly disagree |
| ques2 | 2 | disagree |
| ques2 | 3 | neutral |
| ques3 | 4 | agree |
| ques3 | 3 | neutral |
| ques3 | 4 | agree |
| ques3 | 5 | strongly agree |
| ques4 | 2 | disagree |
| ques4 | 1 | strongly disagree |
| ques4 | 3 | neutral |
| ques4 | 4 | agree |

However, when I run the code, I get inconsistencies in the numbers of the x-axis. I want all 4 questions to have the same amount of responders. In this example, 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `count` before plotting the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(question, choices) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = n, y = question, fill = choices), position = "stack") +
  ggtitle("mask likert scale questions") +
  ylab("questions") +
  xlab("# of people") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(question = c("ques1", "ques1", "ques1", "ques1", 
"ques2", "ques2", "ques2", "ques2", "ques3", "ques3", "ques3", 
"ques3", "ques4", "ques4", "ques4", "ques4"), value = c(5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), choices = c("strongly agree", 
"strongly agree", "agree", "agree", "strongly disagree", "strongly disagree", 
"disagree", "neutral", "agree", "neutral", "agree", "strongly agree", 
"disagree", "strongly disagree", "neutral", "agree")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same graph I got before. I also changed the variables question and choices to factors in case that would help but to no avail. I instead get this error: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): x

Comment: You don't get the graph as shown in my image when you use the code in my answer? If you `plyr` loaded try using `dplyr::count`. I updated my answer to include the data which I am using in a reproducible form so that you can copy and try it. Let me know what you get.

Comment: yes, your code + data works for me, however, when I try it on my full dataset, it does not work. I get this error now Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('gg', 'ggplot')"

Comment: What is the exact code that you are using to get the above error? It seems you are applying the code to a plot whereas you need to apply it to a dataframe.

Comment: `covid_survey_masks %>%
  dplyr::count(question, choices) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = value, y = question, fill = choices), position = "stack") +
  ggtitle("mask likert scale questions") +
  ylab("questions") +
  xlab("# of people") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

Comment: I am not using `aes(x = value` in my answer. It is `x = n`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228506/discussion-between-neuroandstats-and-ronak-shah).